# Type cannot be a member of an object?

Tags: c++, class, types

I cannot compile the following codes:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    T x;
    typedef T type;
};


int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    using T = a.type;
    T t;
    
    return 0;
}
```

It reported an error saying:

```
error: unknown type name 'a'
    using T = a.type;
```

Does this mean that the object `a` doesn't have `type` as one of its members? And a type cannot be a member of an object, is that right?

Comment: You may be looking for `decltype(a)::type`. But you're correct that types and variables are two *categorically* different things.

Answer (score 5):

`type` is not a *data member* of the `a` object instance. So no, you can't access `type` using the `.` or `->` operators on an instance of `A`.

`type` is a *nested type* of the `A` class. You have to use the `::` operator to access it, eg:

`using T = A<int>::type;`

Or

`using T = decltype(a)::type;`

Comment: Should it be `using T = A<int>::type`, or is the `<int>` optional?

Comment: @qrsngky no, it is required, that was a typo on my part. I have fixed it